# How to read multiple objects in a JSON file with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, list, jackson, jackson-databind

I have written some code which saves the contents of a `List<Class>` to a JSON file, which looks kinda like this:

```
{ "firstName": "Name", "lastName": "LastName", "Email": "Email" } { "firstName": "Name2", "lastName": "LastName2", "Email": "Email2" }
```

Now I'm trying to input this file into my program, which works but only the first JSON Object is being returned. This is my code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode readFile = mapper.readTree(new File("path/to/file.json"));
```

How can I read the full JSON file and how can I add the contents of it to the same List mentioned above?
Every tutorial etc. I stumble upon only explains this using a single object.
Thank you!

Comment: Your `JSON` payload is not valid. If you want to store more than one element you need to store it as a `JSON Array` - `[{...}, {...}]`. When you store them as `{...} {...}` `Jackson` reads first object and skip rest of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

Create a user class like this:

```
public class User {
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // Setters and getters
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
String json = yourJson;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User[] userArray = mapper.readValue(json, User[].class);
List<User> userList = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, User[].class));
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. How would I be able to write an array using Jackson Library? Since I'm reading from a JSON file not a String.